# Verificar se sites estão funcionando, php

Tags: php

Oi, estou querendo fazer um checagem em vários links, verificar se estão funcionando, estou usando o código abaixo para isso, porem só funciona quando testo localmente no servidor do meu pc, quando subo ele para o servidor de hospedagem não funciona corretamente.
No servidor de hospedagem os links que possuem portas tipo http://179.106.7.93:5656/System, não mostra como Operacional mesmo estando.
Poderiam me ajudar, ou ate me passar outra estrategia, até porque o que estou usando demora muito o carregamento.
To usando banco Mysql para armazenar os links

```
function url_existe($url1) {
    $ch = curl_init($url1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
    curl_exec($ch);
    $code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    curl_close($ch);
    return ($code == 200); // verifica se recebe "status OK"
}

while($lista_url_a = mysql_fetch_assoc($lista_url)) {
    $url = $lista_url_a['url'];
    $id_url = $lista_url_a['id'];


$url2 = $url;
if (url_existe($url2))
        $atualiza_url = mysql_query("update url set status = 'OPERANTE' where id= $id_url");
    else
        $atualiza_url = mysql_query("update url set status = 'INOPERANTE' where id= $id_url");

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Tente a seguinte função

```
function get_http_response_code($domain1) {
    $headers = get_headers($domain1);
    return substr($headers[0], 9, 3);
}    

function url_existe($domain1){

    $get_http_response_code = get_http_response_code($domain1);

    if ( $get_http_response_code == 200 ) {
       return "OPERANTE";
    } else {
       return "INOPERANTE";
    }
}



while($lista_url_a = mysql_fetch_assoc($lista_url)) {
    $url = $lista_url_a['url'];
    $id_url = $lista_url_a['id'];


    $url2 = $url;
    if (url_existe($url2) == "OPERANTE"){
        $atualiza_url = mysql_query("update url set status = 'OPERANTE' where id= $id_url");
    }else{
        $atualiza_url = mysql_query("update url set status = 'INOPERANTE' where id= $id_url");

    }
}
```

Comment: oi amigo, ocorreu o mesmo problema, na minha rede local funciona, mostrando realmente quem esta ativo, mas quando subo pra hospedagem não funciona